# How to use "hidden" Sandbox in iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, sandbox

I have this [code](https://jsfiddle.net/y065chrk/):

```html
<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin" 
src="//sportsbay.org/embed/72691/1/fc-juarez-vs-chivas-guadalajara-live.html" 
width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

If I use it without: `sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin"` it works well.
But when I add the sandbox code it says: "Sandboxing is not allowed"

Is it possible to somehow force to use sandbox without getting that error?

Answer (score 1):

No.

The site has code which detects it is sandboxed and refuses to display the content when it is.

Presumably, this is because they use features you are blocking in order to make money on their (looks at the name of the site) presumably copyright-infringing content.